# SKErrorUnknown: User closed express checkout

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I am getting this error on failed transaction.
If user close payment screen transaction should return **SKErrorPaymentCancelled**. But from some users we are **SKErrorUnknown** with message **User closed express checkout**

Does anyone experienced this error? How this error could be triggered?